# Persist cookie across multiple HTTPWebRequest call (.net)

Tags: web-services, cookies, httpwebrequest, cross-domain, cookiecontainer

I have a webpage that need to access webservice at other domain. Due to cross domain policy in browser, I create a server side service as a proxy. I'm using server side HttpWebRequest (.net) to call a web service that require authentication and return the json to the javascript. However, i faced few issues :

1. I'm currently hardcode the username and password because HttpWebRequest seems to have no function to allow me to prompt for username and password. There is no popup dialog for login. So, can I force the HttpWebRequest to prompt for username and password just like the XMLHttpRequest (javascipt version) do?
2. Due to the 1st issue,  i noticed that i might need to create a dummy login page that get username and pwd and then send request to the web service. if it success, then it means the login credential is correct. However, right after this, i still have alot of other request to the webservice. The cookie of the HttpWebRequest seems to last only for that request call only. It is not stored inside the normal local cookie storage. (I check the browser and dont find it). How can I store the cookies inside the CookieContainer to the HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies so that i dont need to login again. I dont want to handle every request call by attaching the CookieContainer because there's a lot of request.

Comment: Does the external webservice provide you a JSONP APIs to overcome cross-domain restrictions? Can you bind your proxy service and the external service via OAuth2?

Comment: No, the webservice do not provide JSONP. :( I'm not sure about OAuth2. How can I achieve that?

Comment: It's again depends on the external webservice, if it supports OAuth2 interface. If yes, your proxy can authorize itself in the service and then issue requests to the service on behalf of a user.